# 14.04.2 apt-get: segfault: error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19

Tags: 14.04, apt, segmentation-fault

I'm fairly new to Linux so please forgive some ignorance!

I've installed 14.04.2 Server 3 times now on a Dell Poweredge C6220.

Every time the installation appears to complete without error yet as soon as I
do an apt-get update on my first login ( and any subsequent sessions ) I get a segfault.

```
root@linux4:~# apt-get update
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've run a 24 hour memory diagnostic without any errors. 
Both Drives ( raid 1 ) pass disk diagnostics and have no reported bad blocks.

Occasionally apt-get update runs partially then segfaults.

Don't really know where to go from here to troubleshoot this and grateful for any help/suggestions.  Tails of DMESG, syslog & kern.log below

DMESG:

```
root@linux4:~# dmesg | grep segfault
[ 1169.406414] apt-get[1993]: segfault at 7fb00e1a4858 ip 00007fb00df30d00 sp 00007fff82d442d8 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7fb00ded7000+e6000]
[ 1646.182716] apt-get[2053]: segfault at 7f05f5ff1290 ip 00007f05f5d7d170 sp 00007fffef93fcf8 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7f05f5d24000+e6000]
[ 1708.972623] apt-get[2100]: segfault at 7f5eb039d668 ip 00007f5eb0129920 sp 00007fffd6c2a168 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7f5eb00d0000+e6000]
[ 2356.949919] apt-cache[2120]: segfault at 7f21436b3ab0 ip 00007f21434a169b sp 00007fffee4c5220 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7f21433e7000+e6000]
root@linux4:~#
```

SYSLOG:

```
root@linux4:/var/log# tail -30 syslog 
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.744701] init: dovecot main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.750458] init: dovecot main process (1719) terminated with status 89
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.750464] init: dovecot main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.755795] init: dovecot main process (1722) terminated with status 89
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.755801] init: dovecot main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.761003] init: dovecot main process (1726) terminated with status 89
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.761009] init: dovecot main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.766503] init: dovecot main process (1729) terminated with status 89
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.766509] init: dovecot main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.771619] init: dovecot main process (1732) terminated with status 89
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.771625] init: dovecot main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.776762] init: dovecot main process (1735) terminated with status 89
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.776768] init: dovecot main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.781677] init: dovecot main process (1739) terminated with status 89
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.781683] init: dovecot main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.786574] init: dovecot main process (1742) terminated with status 89
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.786580] init: dovecot main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.792069] init: dovecot main process (1745) terminated with status 89
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   36.792075] init: dovecot respawning too fast, stopped
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 postfix/master[1780]: daemon started -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
May 15 16:00:09 linux4 kernel: [   37.390824] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
May 15 16:00:14 linux4 ntpdate[1423]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset 0.182856 sec
May 15 16:00:16 linux4 kernel: [   44.107385] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
May 15 16:00:16 linux4 acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 6
May 15 16:00:29 linux4 ntpdate[1890]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset 0.176762 sec
May 15 16:17:01 linux4 CRON[1966]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 15 16:19:01 linux4 kernel: [ 1169.406414] apt-get[1993]: segfault at 7fb00e1a4858 ip 00007fb00df30d00 sp 00007fff82d442d8 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7fb00ded7000+e6000]
May 15 16:26:58 linux4 kernel: [ 1646.182716] apt-get[2053]: segfault at 7f05f5ff1290 ip 00007f05f5d7d170 sp 00007fffef93fcf8 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7f05f5d24000+e6000]
May 15 16:28:01 linux4 kernel: [ 1708.972623] apt-get[2100]: segfault at 7f5eb039d668 ip 00007f5eb0129920 sp 00007fffd6c2a168 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7f5eb00d0000+e6000]
May 15 16:38:48 linux4 kernel: [ 2356.949919] apt-cache[2120]: segfault at 7f21436b3ab0 ip 00007f21434a169b sp 00007fffee4c5220 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7f21433e7000+e6000]
root@linux4:/var/log#
```

KERN.LOG:

```
root@linux4:/var/log# tail -30 kern.log
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.179288] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.179290] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.179295] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.179320] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.179331] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.179344] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.186378] checking generic (90000000 500000) vs hw (90000000 1000000)
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.186378] fb: switching to astdrmfb from VESA VGA
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.397933] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.398280] fbcon: astdrmfb (fb0) is primary device
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.427082] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x64
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.467054] ast 0000:05:00.0: fb0: astdrmfb frame buffer device
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.467055] ast 0000:05:00.0: registered panic notifier
May 15 15:59:56 linux4 kernel: [   24.486141] [drm] Initialized ast 0.1.0 20120228 for 0000:05:00.0 on minor 0
May 15 15:59:57 linux4 kernel: [   24.693836] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): em2: link is not ready
May 15 16:00:00 linux4 kernel: [   28.453003] igb 0000:02:00.3 em2: igb: em2 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
May 15 16:00:00 linux4 kernel: [   28.453128] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): em2: link becomes ready
May 15 16:00:08 linux4 kernel: [   36.174791] audit_printk_skb: 24 callbacks suppressed
May 15 16:00:08 linux4 kernel: [   36.174794] audit: type=1400 audit(1431702008.652:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1565 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 15 16:00:08 linux4 kernel: [   36.174801] audit: type=1400 audit(1431702008.652:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1565 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 15 16:00:08 linux4 kernel: [   36.174805] audit: type=1400 audit(1431702008.652:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1565 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 15 16:00:08 linux4 kernel: [   36.175115] audit: type=1400 audit(1431702008.652:23): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1565 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 15 16:00:08 linux4 kernel: [   36.175118] audit: type=1400 audit(1431702008.652:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1565 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 15 16:00:08 linux4 kernel: [   36.175280] audit: type=1400 audit(1431702008.652:25): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1565 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 15 16:00:08 linux4 kernel: [   36.218917] audit: type=1400 audit(1431702008.696:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1567 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 15 16:00:16 linux4 kernel: [   44.107385] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
May 15 16:19:01 linux4 kernel: [ 1169.406414] apt-get[1993]: segfault at 7fb00e1a4858 ip 00007fb00df30d00 sp 00007fff82d442d8 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7fb00ded7000+e6000]
May 15 16:26:58 linux4 kernel: [ 1646.182716] apt-get[2053]: segfault at 7f05f5ff1290 ip 00007f05f5d7d170 sp 00007fffef93fcf8 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7f05f5d24000+e6000]
May 15 16:28:01 linux4 kernel: [ 1708.972623] apt-get[2100]: segfault at 7f5eb039d668 ip 00007f5eb0129920 sp 00007fffd6c2a168 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7f5eb00d0000+e6000]
May 15 16:38:48 linux4 kernel: [ 2356.949919] apt-cache[2120]: segfault at 7f21436b3ab0 ip 00007f21434a169b sp 00007fffee4c5220 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.19[7f21433e7000+e6000]
root@linux4:/var/log#
```

Comment: Could you also add `/var/log/mail.log` and for your apt-get update segfault example, is it giving any more output  on the console after the command input, or is it instantly to segfault?